# How to use array props in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Trying to learn the basics, I got an array in the parent component (App.vue)

```
data() {
 return {
  fruits: [
    "apple",
    "pear",
    "cherry" 
  ], 
 };
},
```

I want to be able to have the same component 3 times for each fruit

```
<Fruit  v-for="(fruit, index) in fruits" :key="index"/>
```

And this is the props feature Fruit.vue component (the child component)

```
 props: {
  fruits: {type: Array, required: false},
}
```

How should I write the code so it displays each fruit in their "own" component in the  tag of Fruit.vue

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. Why do you want an array as a prop, if you want the component only for a single fruit? And you aren't passing anything to the component anyway.

Comment: "Fruit" (singular) doesn't need a list of fruits. It likely should receive `name` prop, not `fruits`

Answer (score 2):

You want to have a fruit component that accepts only a string from the array.

Fruit component

```js
<template>
<div class="fruit">
{{ props.fruit }} 
</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts"
export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    fruit: { type: String, required: true }
  }
  setup(props) {
    return { props }
  }
}
</script>
```

inside app.vue

```html
<Fruit  v-for="fruit in fruits" :key="fruit" :fruit="fruit"/>
```